# ui-grid randomly displaying $$Hash Key instead of grid data

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have a ui-grid that I update with data - sometimes it seems to display only one column, titled $$Hash Key - despite the data being there and being correct. Does anybody know what the cause of this is, or how to resolve it? The behaviour is sporadic - sometimes it only displays $$Hash Key with column values like "uiGrid-006", sometimes it displays the data correctly.  My code is fairly straight forward:

```
    MyService.create($scope.myData, function(data, status, headers, config) {

    $scope.gridOptions.data.push(data);
 }, function(data, status, headers, config) {
});
```

My ui-grid is defined as:

```
<div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-pagination ui-grid-selection ui-grid-exporter></div>
```

Comment: Sounds like a race condition between grid initialization and fetching your data. Are you pre-defining your grid column definitions?

Comment: In fact, no. I will try that. Thanks!